# jQuery on click to check if it has a div with a certain class and then change the value of a different class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

The code that i am writing is for an application where you select an icon and you get the css line displayed so you easily copy paste it and use it for another project. I'm having trouble with the $(this) selector. I have several divs with the "glyph-holder" class and it doesn't matter wich one I press, it always changes the "copy_text" div's value to the same class, the first one. I want it to change it to the div that i pressed.

The html that i have is:

```
<div id="copy_text">Select icon</div>
<div class="glyph-holder">
    <div class="glyph">
        <div class="icon-flip-horizontal"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="beschrijving-bij-glyph">
         icon-flip-horizontal
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript that i currently have is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var displayText = "Empty";

    $(".glyph-holder").click(function(){

        if($(this).has("icon-flip-horizontal")){
            displayText = "icon-flip-horizontal";
        }else if($(this).has("icon-flip-vertical")){
            displayText = "icon-flip-vertical";
        }

        $("#copy_text").text(displayText);
    });
});
```

Comment: `hasClass()`, not `has()`

Comment: I tried that aswell but it doesn't work, it always returns empty when i use the .hasClass method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector in `has()` is missing the `.` prefix for the class. You also need to check the `length` property of the resulting jQuery object. Try this:

```js
var displayText = "Empty";

$(".glyph-holder").click(function() {
  if ($(this).has(".icon-flip-horizontal").length) {
    displayText = "icon-flip-horizontal";
  } else if ($(this).has(".icon-flip-vertical").length) {
    displayText = "icon-flip-vertical";
  }
  $("#copy_text").text(displayText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="copy_text">Select icon</div>
<div class="glyph-holder">
  <div class="glyph">
    <div class="icon-flip-horizontal"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="beschrijving-bij-glyph">
    icon-flip-horizontal
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not currently specifying that the `has` is looking for a class, also `.has()` returns a jQuery object and therefore `.length` should be used to test for the number of elements. Try this instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var displayText = "Empty";

    $(".glyph-holder").click(function(){

        if($(this).has(".icon-flip-horizontal").length){
            displayText = "icon-flip-horizontal";
        }else if($(this).has(".icon-flip-vertical").length){
            displayText = "icon-flip-vertical";
        }

        $("#copy_text").text(displayText);
    });
});
```

Note, the `.` in `.has(".icon-flip-horizontal")` is important since it's referencing a class.

Comment: When not adding the . it also finds the first class, the horizontal one. But it does not find the second one, the vertical one. Whatever div i click with the class .glyph-holder it always uses the horizontal one

Comment: Ok I see, it's returning a jQuery object so you should be doing this instead: `$(this).has(".icon-flip-horizontal").length`. I've updated my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting div by `id` so it will target only one div. You can get the `copy_text` div by the div using `prev` function.
$(document).ready(function(){

```
var displayText = "Empty";

$(".glyph-holder").click(function(){

    if($(this).has(".icon-flip-horizontal")){
        displayText = "icon-flip-horizontal";
    }else if($(this).has(".icon-flip-vertical")){
        displayText = "icon-flip-vertical";
    }

    $(this).prev().text(displayText);
  });
});
```